# Can I make this more efficient? Creating a buffer in Javascript with NodeJS, Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, buffer, performance

I'm getting a lot of data on my socket.io client side that may or may not be complete data and its also potentially BIG data, so I need to make it efficient.  So I have tried my hand at creating a buffer and parsing that into my app. I know there are some streaming/buffering modules available, and I might consider using those if they achieve the goal of being more efficient. Looking forward to seeing your answers and possible arguments on how to best do this.

*Note, bandwidth is not my concern as much as how quickly the client side Javascript can render the data into a browser friendly format.*

Here is what I've got so far.

```
function extended_split(str, separator, max) {
        var out = [],
                index = 0,
                next;

        while (!max || out.length < max - 1 ) {
                next = str.indexOf(separator, index);
                if (next === -1) {
                        break;
                }
                out.push(str.substring(index, next));
                index = next + separator.length;
        }
        out.push(str.substring(index));
        return out;
};  

var buffer = ''; 

// data format "\nOP:ARGS:DATA(could be base64 or 'other' depending on OP)\0";
socket.on('ioSend', function(data) {
    data = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));
    buffer = buffer + data; 
    while(buffer.indexOf('\n') != -1 && extended_split(buffer, '\n', 2)[1].indexOf('\0') != -1)
    {
        splitted = extended_split(extended_split(buffer, '\n', 2)[1], '\0', 2);  
        parse = splitted[0];
        buffer = splitted[1];  
        parse = parse.split(':');
        // Do stuff with parse here                     
    } 
});
```

Comment: the speed of processing the data on client-side will give you different results because its executed on different machines, but on average its not noticeable, i mean is text if your text is not in MB then you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another crack at this and dropped the extended split idea and came up with this.

```
socket.on('ioSend', function(data) {                                    // receive command from socket.io
    if (safeBrowser) {                                                  // IE < 10 doesn't support Uint16Array
        var xdata = new Uint16Array(data);
        data = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, xdata);
        buffer = buffer + data;                                         // Update the buffer with most recent ioSend data  
    }
    else {                                                              // So we have to kludge this in for IE < 10 
        var xdata = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            xdata += String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        }
        buffer = buffer + xdata;                                         // Update the buffer with most recent ioSend data   
    }
    var splitA = [];
    var splitB = [];
    while(buffer.indexOf(d1) != -1 && buffer.indexOf(d2) != -1)         // While loop reads buffer until there are no commands left to issue
    {
        splitA = buffer.split(d2);                  // Array with rear delimiter
        splitB = splitA[0].split(d1);           
        doParse.call(null, splitB[1]);              // This should be an @command
        splitB = null;
        splitA.shift();                             // Shift array
        buffer = splitA.join(d2);                   // Update buffer from shifted array with rear delimiter
    }     
});
```

It's really fast in all my unit tests and does the job really well.  I'm working on an implementation that doesn't use socket.io as @GeoPhoenix suggested but until then this works good.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling your own buffer builder/parser its ok, but you can spent double the time working and maintaining it, from just getting a production ready script.

Now from my point of view, i would first drop `socket.io` for your case, since **`it just doesn't transmit binary as it should`** , there are other modules that transmit binary https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs which are better suited for binary transmissions over websocket protocol.

i would also try http://bsonspec.org/ *(check implementations for node modules)*, which encodes your json into binary, this way you could skip the whole problem with building and maintaining the buffer parser/builder.

Comment: The data portion is more than likely to be base64 and not binary, but could also be 'other' (I should have clarified), bandwidth is not a concern as much as throughput is. I basically need to get whatever might come down that pipe and turn it into browser friendly data as fast as possible. Thank you for the module links, I'll definitely take a look. As of right now socket.io is an integral part of my app for more than just this portion, but it's definitely worth looking at alternatives.